# how to vertically center images of random height in carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am trying to add the vertical centering which is on http://jsfiddle.net/ev2wD/2/ to the logos in my jquery carousel http://apple.mdsc1.com/slick-1.6.0/ourpartners.html

how do i do that? the container for my logos is:-

```
  <section class="regular slider">
<div>
  <a href="http://www.mobileiron.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/mobileiron.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="http://www.vmware.com/products/enterprise-mobility-management.html" target="_blank"><img src="images/airwatch.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="http://www.sap.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/sap.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="https://www.jamf.com/products/jamf-pro/" target="_blank"><img src="images/jamf.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="https://products.office.com/en-us/home" target="_blank"><img src="images/ms.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="http://www.cisco.com/c/m/en_us/solutions/strategic-partners/apple.html" target="_blank"><img src="images/cisco.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

Add it to your `.slick-track` class. Works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you really want to do is assign a class to each of the images, and then vertically align them:

```
img.<your_clss_name> {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

That will vertically align all images by their middle point.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.home-container-img {
    height: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
    text-align: center; /* align the inline(-block) elements horizontally */
    font: 0/0 a;
}



.home-img img {
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle; /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
    font: 16px/1 Arial sans-serif; /* <-- reset the font property */
}
```

```html
<div style="height:70px; width:100px; border:1px solid black; ">

<div class="home-container-img">
            <div class="home-img img">
                <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
        
        </div>
```

just like this: